# Quartz: skipping duplicate job fires scheduled with same fire time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to Quartz and stuck on duplicate job runs. 
They was caused by two triggers which has overlapping fire times.

Is there any Quartz "out-of-the-box" functionality which will prevent duplicate fires of same job with multiple attached triggers?

Or maybe there is some third-party `Trigger` implementation which allows to combine schedule's with proper fire time calculation which will prevent duplicate fire times?

Or maybe i can somehow combine multiple schedules?

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

For the clarity:

```
public static class MyJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("My Job at " + DateUtils.toDateTimeString(context.getFireTime()) +  " by " +
                context.getTrigger().getKey().getName());
    }
}

startScheduler() {

    final Set<Trigger> triggers = new HashSet<Trigger>();
    triggers.add(TriggerBuilder.<CronScheduleBuilder>newTrigger().withIdentity("every 3 secs").
            withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/3 * * * * ? *")).build());
    triggers.add(TriggerBuilder.<CronScheduleBuilder>newTrigger().withIdentity("every 2 secs").
            withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/2 * * * * ? *")).build());

    final Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties).getScheduler();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).build(), triggers, false);
    scheduler.start();

}
```

And the logs:

- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:26.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:27.000 by every 3 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:28.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at ***01.11.2013T23:19:30.000*** by *every 2 secs*
- My Job at ***01.11.2013T23:19:30.001*** by *every 3 secs*
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:32.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:33.000 by every 3 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:34.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at ***01.11.2013T23:19:36.000*** by *every 2 secs*
- My Job at ***01.11.2013T23:19:36.001*** by *every 3 secs*
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:38.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:39.000 by every 3 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:19:40.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at ***01.11.2013T23:19:42.001*** by *every 2 secs*
- My Job at ***01.11.2013T23:19:42.002*** by *every 3 secs*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found that `TriggerListener`'s suitable for this task:

```
scheduler.getListenerManager().addTriggerListener(new TriggerListener() {

    private Date lastFireTime = null;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "prevent-duplicate-fires";
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerFired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        final Date fireTime = context.getScheduledFireTime();
        if (lastFireTime != null && fireTime.equals(lastFireTime)) {
            return true;
        }
        lastFireTime = fireTime;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger) {
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context, Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {
    }
});
```

Looks like it works:

- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:14.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:15.000 by every 3 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:16.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:18.000 by every 2 secs
- ---> Should fire but skipped - My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:18.000 by every 3 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:20.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:21.000 by every 3 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:22.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:24.000 by every 2 secs
- ---> Should fire but skipped - My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:24.000 by every 3 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:26.000 by every 2 secs
- My Job at 01.11.2013T23:46:27.000 by every 3 secs

Answer (score 0):

This is a helpful answer to stop a job from running.  In addition to safe guard against never calling a duplicate job use the annotation @DisallowConcurrentExecution on the class that implements job.