# How configure Quartz for doing the job only once at the same time?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

I am using Quartz in Spring Boot project. I've a job which is executing from cron and can be executed manually. How can I configure for doing this job only once at the same time.
@DisallowConcurrentExecution would be fit if job couldn't be manually triggered, but in this case it's not enough.

Comment: Why wouldn't `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` that is exactly what it is for. If the job is already running it won't allow another one, regardless the way the job has started. So unless you are manually starting it outside of Quartz (which you then shouldn't do) this should just work, else refactor your code to launch the job through Quartz both manually and scheduled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@DisallowConcurrentExecution should work ,else you can also try implementing a listener and veto executionjob based on your need .
ref- [Quartz: skipping duplicate job fires scheduled with same fire time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733981/quartz-skipping-duplicate-job-fires-scheduled-with-same-fire-time)